# Git CA fails but certificate is valid (gitea)

Tags: git, ssl, gitea

We are using **gitea** to manage some repositories. Everything was working fine until 2 days ago. Now I try to pull from the repo and I get `server certificate verification failed`.

Facts

1. The server is running gitea (digital ocean pre-configured server) and cerbot is managing the certificate.
2. Certbot says certificate is valid and will not renew (which is correct)
3. Certificate validity also verified with openssl client

```sh
openssl s_client -servername git.the-domain.com -connect git.the-domain.com:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates
notBefore=Sep 21 09:00:33 2021 GMT
notAfter=Dec 20 09:00:32 2021 GMT
```

The complete error (from ansible) is the following

```
https://user:token@git.the-domain.com/some-repo/ansible.git/': server certificate verification failed. 
CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none"
    ],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

Hint: If I disable the SSL verification from git everything works fine. However that's not really an option I am willing to embrace on production servers :)

```sh
# Disabling ssl check removes the issue - but it's not an option.
git config --global http.sslverify false
```

I am at a loss, here, any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Ah, looks like I was left out of the loop, the cause appears to be the expiry of the root certificate from letsencrypt. Any handy guides on how to add the new root CA to Ubuntu 18.04 (openssl v1.1.1g)?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate